# Spring MVC3 access HttpServletRequest

Tags: servlets, spring-mvc, request

I would like to handle request and session attributes myself rather than leaving it to Spring `@SessionAttributes`, for login or cookies handling for example.
I just cannot figure out how to access the `HttpRequest` from within a controller. I need a way to go a layer above the `@RequestAttribute` and access the `HttpRequest` itself.
With Stripes in used to do this by implementing an `ApplicationContext` and calling `getAttribute()`.

Also, passing the `HttpServletRequest` as parameter seems not to work:

```java
@RequestMapping(value="/")
public String home(HttpServletRequest request){   
    System.out.println(""+request.getSession().getCreationTime());
    return "home"; 
}
```

Why does this method not print anything?

Answer (score 1):

Attach a debugger and confirm that your controller method is called.

Check the following:

1. Are you sending a POST request? Then you need to specify the method name with the method parameter: `@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.POST)`
2. Is your controller properly detected by Spring via the `@Controller` annotation?